# mixed linear model for repeated-measures

Tags: regression, mixed-model, python, statsmodels

I am trying to analyze if I can expect some differences between regions in the following dataset.

I believe (I am not sure at all) that one way to do this is to use statsmodels:

I have got 4 subjects, for which we have two measures that are done simultaneously (region-region: 23b-9 and 23b-8A) at each time point and are repeated several times (sessions).

1. no treatment or anything between the different times, it just here to improve the statistics.
2. The measures are not quantitative across the sessions, only within (between 23b-9 and 23b-8A) so we can expect different baselines across the repetitions.

I am only interested in the differences: 23b-9 vs 23b-8A

[image]

Base on this example:
https://apimirror.com/statsmodels/examples/notebooks/generated/mixed_lm_example
I thought that the following example would be a good way to do it?

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

md = smf.mixedlm("correlation ~ region-region", good_correl_pcc, groups=good_correl_pcc["subject"], re_formula="~sessions")
mdf = md.fit(method=["lbfgs"])
```

however, I am still hesitating with this one too?

```
md = smf.mixedlm("correlation ~ sessions*region-region", good_correl_pcc, groups=good_correl_pcc["subject"])
mdf = md.fit(method=["lbfgs"])
```

Or maybe it is something else?

Also,

With proposition 1:
I have got this result:

```
             Mixed Linear Model Regression Results
===============================================================
Model:              MixedLM   Dependent Variable:   correlation
No. Observations:   44        Method:               REML       
No. Groups:         4         Scale:                0.0104     
Min. group size:    8         Log-Likelihood:       28.6267    
Max. group size:    14        Converged:            Yes        
Mean group size:    11.0                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------
                     Coef.  Std.Err.   z    P>|z| [0.025 0.975]
---------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept             0.672    0.041 16.555 0.000  0.592  0.751
region[T.PG-9]       -0.208    0.031 -6.766 0.000 -0.269 -0.148
Group Var             0.000                                    
Group x sessions Cov  0.000    0.005                           
sessions Var          0.000    0.001                           
===============================================================
```

I understand that according to the result I may have an effect (Intercept).
Out of curiosity:

- What region[T.PG-9], Group Var, Group x sessions Cov, sessions Var mean?
- Is there a way to print the full pvalue (not just 0.000)?
- is there any pre-requisites or posthoc tests necessary for this analysis?

Thank you so much for your help!

---

After talking with a colleague it seems that the best way to do it:

md = smf.mixedlm("correlation ~ subject*region-region", good_correl_pcc, groups=good_correl_pcc["sessions"])

or

md = smf.mixedlm("correlation ~ subject+region-region", good_correl_pcc, groups=good_correl_pcc["sessions"])

the problem in my model

md = smf.mixedlm("correlation ~ region-region", good_correl_pcc, groups=good_correl_pcc["subject"], re_formula="~sessions")

is that:
'sessions' is treated as a (random) slope. When in my example it is not.

to me the problem with the model of Kerby
md = smf.mixedlm("correlation ~ region-region", good_correl_pcc, groups="subject")

is that it does not pair "sessions"

Hopefully this time I am right?

---

Finally, it seems that using a nested model make more sense

md = smf.mixedlm("correlation ~ region + C(subject)", good_correl_pcc, groups=good_correl_pcc["sessions"])

Answer (score 0):

If you type `mdf.params`, or `mdf.params["Group Var"]` you will get the parameter estimates with more decimal places.  However it appears that the RMLE is on the boundary, i.e. the estimates may truly be zero.

You only have four people, which is not a lot to estimate three variance parameters.  You might want to start with something simpler like

`md = smf.mixedlm("correlation ~ region-region", good_correl_pcc, groups="subject")`

Another possibility would be to difference the two repeated measures for each person/session, leading to a dataset with 22 observations.  That data could then be modeled using a random intercept model or GEE.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Using md = smf.mixedlm("correlation ~ region-region", good_correl_pcc, groups="subject"): I have got "LinAlgError: Singular matrix". Also, I tested mdf.params["Group Var"]  and the result is:                                                                                                                                                                           0.04377090621481011. It does not make sens to me. 
Also, I explored a little bit the parameters of mdf, but I can't find what would be the command to print the full pvalue.

Comment: `mdf.pvalues` will give you the raw p-values, at the full precision to which they are computed.

Comment: When calling `fit`, you can try several algorithms, like `method=["Powell", "LBFGS", "CG"]`.  Starting with Powell (which is derivative free and stable) sometimes helps.  However note that if the RLME of the variance parameter is zero, none of these algorithms will be able to guarantee convergence.

Comment: thank you very much!